# What's new in Unity 2D 5.2?

Tags: unity-2d, development

I've really enjoyed using Unity 2D 4.12 in 11.10. It's very fast, and it works better with some games than Unity (because of Compiz). In Precise Pangolin, I notice that the new version is 5.2. Can someone provide information about user-visible changes between the two versions?

(I didn't notice until afterwards that the version was released only half an hour before I asked. That's completely accidental :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have more infos about the new version of Unity 2D, you can take a look at this [article here](http://iloveubuntu.net/unity-2d-52-released-numerous-improvements-ubuntu-1204-lts).

Comment: A more detailed changelog is available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/unity-2d/+changelog)